# How can I replace the LZ77 ntfs-compression with a faster one in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I've read this article about http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/data-compression/ and I wonder if it's possible to replace the standart LZ77 compression with a faster one in Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not unless you modify the `Ntfs.sys` kernel driver (the source code of which is not available outside Microsoft).

Comment: Can you write a kernel module and use the ntfs-3g driver?

Comment: Yes, you can write kernel drivers in C/C++; Microsoft provides an IFS (installable file system) development kit.